# Редирект в контроллере

Tags: java, spring-boot

У меня есть таблица с компьютерами и таблица с их характеристиками.

Когда в таблице с компьютерами я нажимаю на конкретный комп, открываются его характеристики. проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь редактировать эти характеристики, я не знаю как мне вернуться обратно к характеристикам конкретной модели. что нужно прописать в `return` в данном случае?

Вот мой контроллер. Внизу метод editChar, в котором необходимо правильно указать в return куда возвращаться:

```
 @Controller
 public class PcCharsController {

final private PcRepository pcRepository;
final private PcCharactRepository pcCharactRepository;

public PcCharsController(PcRepository pcRepository, PcCharactRepository pcCharactRepository) {
    this.pcRepository = pcRepository;
    this.pcCharactRepository = pcCharactRepository;
}

@GetMapping("pc/{id}/characts")
public String pcCharList(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) throws Exception{

    Pc pc = pcRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("PostId " + id + " not found"));
    List<PcCharacts> pcChars = pc.getCharacts();
    model.addAttribute("model", pc.getModel());
    model.addAttribute("pcChars", pcChars);
    return "charList";
}

@PostMapping("pc/{id}/characts")
public String addChar(@RequestParam Long id,
                      @RequestParam String name,
                      @RequestParam String value,
                      Model model) throws Exception {
    Pc pc = pcRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("PostId " + id + " not found"));
    PcCharacts pcCharacts = new PcCharacts(name, value, pc);
    pcCharactRepository.save(pcCharacts);
    List<PcCharacts> pcChars = pc.getCharacts();
    model.addAttribute("pcChars", pcChars);
    return "redirect:";
}

@GetMapping("/charact/{pcChars}")
public String editCharact(@PathVariable PcCharacts pcChars, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("pcChars", pcChars);
    return "editPcChar";
}

//HERE IS A PROBLEM
@PostMapping("pc/characts/save") //OR HERE
public String charSave(@RequestParam String name,
                       @RequestParam String value,
                       @RequestParam("id") PcCharacts pcChars){
    pcChars.setName(name);
    pcChars.setValue(value);
    pcCharactRepository.save(pcChars);
    return "redirect:/pc/{id}/characts"; //HERE
}

@GetMapping("/charact/delete/{id}")
public String deletePc(@PathVariable("id") PcCharacts pcChars){
    pcCharactRepository.delete(pcChars);
    return "redirect:/pc/{id}/";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По хорошему, Вам нужно сделать редирект.

Например:

```
return "redirect: pc/{id}/characts"
```

Если `pc/{id}/characts` у Вас маршрут для страницы с характеристиками (если нет сами подставите нужный)

Answer (score 1):

```
return "redirect: pc/" + pcChars + "/characts";
```